# Chrome Extension using NativeMessaging cannot receive some kind of json data

Tags: c++, json, windows, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

Chrome extension use native messaging to receive json data:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('company.my_application');  
port.onMessage.addListener(function(result) { 
    console.log(result);
});
```

In my C++ program, if  I send a json string `str1[]`, extension can receive it, but if I send `str2[]`, extension can not receive it. 
Is there any problem with this string?

`str2[]` stands for a long string which is a correct Json data, but can't be accepted by extension.
Did any one run into the same problem and resolve it ?

```
char str1[]="{\"Func\":\"test\",\"msg\":\"hello\"}";

char str2[]="{\"Func\":\"test\",\"msg\":\"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\"}";
```

I'm trying to send the length and message as follows:

```
size_t len = strlen(str2);
cout.write(str2, len);
fflush(stdout);
```

I have use these ways to send length:

```
    cout.write((char*)&len, 4);

    putchar ((( char *) &len) [0]);
    putchar ((( char *) &len) [1]);
    putchar ((( char *) &len) [2]);
    putchar ((( char *) &len) [3]);

    putchar(char(((len >> 0) & 0xFF)));
    putchar(char(((len >> 8) & 0xFF)));
    putchar(char(((len >> 16) & 0xFF)));
    putchar(char(((len >> 24) & 0xFF)));
```

Comment: That is an awfully long string, and you might not get good responses regarding it.

Comment: c++ program don't need any response from extension. I hope extension can receive this json data by nativeMassaging and show it.

Comment: I meant as a post here on Stack Overflow, a wall of numbers like that is hard to look at.

Comment: sorry to misread your comment... str2[] stands for a long string whitch is a correct Json data, but can't be accepted by extension. Maybe someone run into the same problem and resolve it.

Comment: Maybe you aren't sending the size properly. Double-check your size calculation. Or better yet, include here the code.

Comment: I have used these three ways

Comment: And `len` is calculated how?

Comment: size_t len=strlen(str2);
 
 cout.write(str2, len);
 fflush(stdout);

Comment: @MinYang Please roll back your edit and post your answer as an answer and accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
unsigned int len = strlen(str2);
```

instead of

```
size_t len = strlen(str2);
```

The [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging) protocol requires that the message is preceded by a 32-bit integer, whereas the bit size of `size_t` is implementation-dependent. On my 64-bit system, `sizeof(size_t)` is 8 (bytes) for example.

Comment: You are right. using unsigned int is better than size_t. I have fixed it, but this is not the reason, extension still can not receive it,

Comment: @MinYang Could you show your complete program (at least the relevant parts) in your question? I took the string from your question and changing `size_t` to `unsigned int` *did* resolve the issue for me.

Comment: I run these code in c++ program thread:
 char str[];//str2
 unsigned int Len = strlen(str);
    putchar(char(((Len >> 0) & 0xFF)));
    putchar(char(((Len >> 8) & 0xFF)));
    putchar(char(((Len >> 16) & 0xFF)));
    putchar(char(((Len >> 24) & 0xFF)));
 printf("%s",str);
 fflush(stdout);

Comment: @MinYang Try `cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Len), 4);` instead.

Comment: @MinYang Add a minimal example in your question that compiles. Otherwise I cannot help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

[OP's solution converted to answer below]

Thanks everyone for comments, I have now fixed this problem.

**Cause**:

The length of `str[]` is `2601(0x29 0x0a 0x00 0x00)`. My IO will automatically insert `Ox0d` before `0x0a`, so my ouput length become 5 bytes, `(0x29 0x0d 0x0a 0x00 0x00)`.

**Solution**:

Change IO mode.

```
#include<io.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
_setmode(fileno(stdout), O_BINARY);
```